# htaccess- file should be accessed only without extension and with extension should be redirected to home url

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a file in my public_directory called `blog.php`, so generally, a user can access that file with `mydomain.com/blog.php`, Now I want two things

1. the user should be able to access the URL `mydomain.com/blog.php` with `mydomain.com/blog`
2. when a user tries to access that file with the extension it should redirect him to home page i.e if the user enters `mydomain.com/blog.php` in the URL bar, he should be redirected (external redirection) to `mydomain.com`

The solution for the first one is

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

the solution for second one is

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ htpp://mydomain.com [R=301,L]
```

And the combined solution should be

```
 RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ htpp://mydomain.com [R=301,L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Individually both solution works fine, But when I combined them, they don't work as expected, it redirects me to the to the home page (`mydomain.com`) even for the URL `mydomain.com/blog`

So why the above solution doesn't work as expected and what would be the correct solution

Thanks!

Comment: "htpp:" looks like a typo to be meant as "http:".

Comment: @MarkusZeller yes, right, but for some reason StackOverflow doesn't allow that in question

Comment: @anubhava Hi anubhava, could you pls look into this question, Thanks!